# What is the lower case $\rho$ in this equation?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation

What is the $\rho$ in this equation where the equation is from this [source](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html)?

It is $\rho$ before an ($s$). Are those zeros both indexes?
This is a product series so does this mean the $\rho(s)$ is only factored in during the $0$th index?

$$P(\tau|\theta) = \rho_0(s_0) \prod_{t=0}^T P(s_{t+1}|s_t, a_t) \pi_\theta (a_t|s_t)$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability that we begins with state $s_0$ is denoted by $\rho_0(s_0)$.

$\pi_\theta(a_t|a_t)$ is the probability that we take action $a_t$ given that  when are at state $s_t$. This is the policy.

$P(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)$ is the probability that if we take action $a_t$ at state $s_t$, we end up at state $s_{t+1}$.

Comment: "The probability that we begins with state s0". This is confusing because to me a probability means a probability. The probability of a coin toss being 50/50. Can this be applied to the probability of a chess game? The state of the chess board being in a start position. I don't understand how probability would be worth mentioning. If the actions of the chess players are zero then the state is zero - no pawns have moved. All chess pieces in starting state. State would be zero. Probability of (s0 | a0) is 100%. I thought Rho had to do with correlation anyways.

Comment: If it is a chess game, if $s_0$ describes the deterministic starting state, then $\rho_0(s_0)$ is $1$. If $s_0$ is an impossible starting sttae, then $\rho_0(s_0)=0$. If it can start at state $s_0$ with probability $0.5$, then $\rho_0(s_0)=0.5$. It has nothing to do with correlation.

Comment: What would be an impossible starting state in chess and in machine learning? So Rho0(s0) is a specific number? What determines the number? I would think the starting state of zero is just s0.

Comment: For a chess game, the pawns are at the second row. if $s_0$ describes the state that the pawn are at the first row, then we know that it is impossible and it should take probability $0$.   As for what determines the number, it depends on the probability distrbution of the starting state.

Comment: " it depends on the probability distrbution of the starting state." So, would the number always be the same for something like a chess game? I know maybe some "games" might have a different initial state, but chess does not.

Comment: For a typical chess, where you encode the pieces on the $64$ locations to represent the state, then yes, there is only one way to start it.